# Error Data Source Configuration Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have this erro, when I tried to run my web app:

> 24-12-2015 13:42:38 ERROR:
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class
>   com.noi.vetrina.config.DataSourceConfig: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>     ... 25 more

This is my `pom.xml`:

```
<org.springframework-version>4.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
<hibernate.version>5.0.5.Final</hibernate.version>


<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there into pom the problem??

EDIT this DataSourceConfig:

```
Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.noi.vetrina.repository" })
@Import({ DataSourceDevConfig.class, DataSourceProdConfig.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:/META-INF/persistence_mysql.properties")
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private static final String DB_TYPE = "mysql_";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY = "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = DB_TYPE + "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Resource(name = "mysql")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * Configures the transaction manager.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Configures the entity manager factory.
     * 
     * @return
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        String pack = environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(pack);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("persistenceUnit");

        Properties jpaProterties = new Properties();
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(DB_TYPE + PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(DB_TYPE + PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, environment.getRequiredProperty(DB_TYPE + PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment.getRequiredProperty(DB_TYPE + PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
        jpaProterties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(DB_TYPE + PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        jpaProterties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        jpaProterties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        jpaProterties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 20);
        jpaProterties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        jpaProterties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);

        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_H");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name", "AUDIT_REVISION");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name", "ACTION_TYPE");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy", "org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name", "AUDIT_REVISION_END");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp", "True");
        jpaProterties.put("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_revend_timestamp_field_name", "AUDIT_REVISION_END_TS");

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProterties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
      return new AuditorAwareBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your spring configuration?

Comment: Also note that it's strange to hardcode a version for spring-context and not for the rest..

Comment: I added the configuration..

Comment: And add the full exception stack trace. Knowing **which** method of **which** class is abstract, and **when** the exception happens is very useful to identify the problem.

Comment: @JBNizet ok, I added it..

Comment: That looks like an incompatibility with Hibernate 5.0.5 (which is quite new) and Spring. Have you tried downgrading the Hibernate version, or to upgrade the Spring version (i.e. use the latest snapshot)?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448957/abstractmethoderror-in-sessionfactoryimpl-when-upgrading-to-hibernate-5

Comment: Turns out that you're calling the method `entityManagerFactory().getObject()` when trying to pass to your `TransactionManager`. Rather than that, you should let Spring call that method by himself, through the annotation `@Bean` and tell to your `TransactionManager` to get the `EntityManagerFactory` from the container.

Comment: please check the config xml file where you create a been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it to downgrade the hibernate version... I'm using the 4.3.11.Final and it works...