# Migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5 and Spring 4 to 5

Tags: spring, hibernate

While migrating from Spring 4 to 5 and Hibernate 4 to 5, I am unable to get a proper sessionFactory bean from Hibernate. The exception I encounter is,

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in x.y.z: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

How do I figure out what is causing this? Or which dependency is causing this?

Comment: This might help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448957/abstractmethoderror-in-sessionfactoryimpl-when-upgrading-to-hibernate-5

Comment: That was helpful. It was an issue with jadira libraries. Updating them to the latest 6.0.1.GA fixed it.