# Spring Boot Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-entitymanager

i have a problem with a spring boot application.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <wro4j.version>1.7.6</wro4j.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.0.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <wrapper.version>3.5.24</wrapper.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR7</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kohsuke.metainf-services</groupId>
        <artifactId>metainf-services</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Datenbank -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If i start the application i get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
at xxxxx.eai.kfz.infrastructure.auth.AuthserverApplication.main(AuthserverApplication.java:60) [classes/:na]

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.9.Final.jar:5.0.9.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

If i start the application with spring-boot-dependencies and version 1.3.6 or 1.3.7 then it works without exception. I tried also all versions from 1.3.6 until 1.4.2.

could you help please

Comment: can you post your bean configurations as well?

Comment: Why don't you just use spring-boot-dependencies with version 1.3.6 or 1.3.7?  If there is another problem, you need to update you question with more detail in order to receive a thorough answer.

Comment: Could it be similar issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775410/spring4-2-1-hibernate5-integrate-abstract-method-error

Comment: OWASP Dependency Check shows some problems in spring-boot-dependencies with version 1.3.6. So i want to use the latest version.